# How to read LongTensor stored on a disk by chunks

Tags: python, numpy, file, buffer, torch

I have `LongTensor` stored on a disk:

```
x = torch.load(filepath)
```

with size `torch.Size([10000])`

Actually, I don't have an opportunity to load it due to RAM limit. And I was advised to use file buffer to read data by smaller chunks. For example to read first number:

```
f = open(filepath)
batch = np.frombuffer(f.read(8), dtype=np.long)
```

`8` in `f.read(8)` because `Long` type takes 8 bytes in torch.

And then convert to torch.
But I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ken/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-80-b32b171befc6>", line 2, in <module>
    batch = np.frombuffer(f.read(8), dtype=np.longlong)
  File "/Users/ken/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Where does the `np.long` come from?

Comment: @AMC I play around with different datatypes, maybe it's wrong.

Comment: I don't know if it's wrong, I was just wondering what it is.